# Bootstrap popover align in middle

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, svg

I am making an interactive svg map with highlights. Now I am using the bootstrap popover but it is aligned above the svg. What I want is to place it direct over the svg in the middle or something.

Here is an [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ozkuqffx/) to see how its build up.

As you can see in the Fiddle i trigger the popover on the `svg` element.

How do I acces this specific popover? I was thinking like this:

```
$('svg').click(function(){
    $('div').find('.popover').css('top', '100px','!important');
})
```

But than it is setting top to 100px when you click the second time (when its closing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i all ready found the solution wrap the svg in a div and give it an `position: relative` and `display: inline-block` than give the `popover class:`

```
.popover {
        .pos-t-l(50%, 50%) !important; (mixin position top-left)
        .translate(-50%; -50%);
    }`
```